# installing laser scanner on Turtlebot 2 for SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, turtlebot, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to install a Hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW laser scanner on a Turtlebot 2 and try the SLAM demo (http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM). I managed to make the sensor work with the urg_node driver (https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node) in groovy, but in RVIZ it is always missing the /laser frame. I suspect I need to configure TF, but I don't know how, I can't add a new node to TF in RVIZ.
Can anybody help, what and how should be adjusted in order to make the laser scanner work in the SLAM demo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60532/installing-laser-scanner-on-turtlebot-2-for-slam/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to use a TF broadcaster to make the connexion between your base_frame and your laser_frame.

Try to use : [static_transform_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher)

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-04-12**:
thanks! it works, I used "rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 /plate_middle_link /laser 1000"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way would be to add that link to the URDF in the robot description. TF is then published automatically. The HECTOR guys have done that to their turtlebot (see [hector_turtlebot_description](http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_turtlebot/hector_turtlebot_description/) ).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1